# Determine weekend based on country

Tags: oracle, plsql, date

I've a table called `BOND` which have columns `BOND NAME`, `COUNTRY of ISSUE` and `ISSUE DATE`

```
BOND  Country  ISSUE_DATE
===========================
B1    INDIA    20-AUG-2017
B2    ISRAEL   18-AUG-2017
```

How do I find the issue date is weekend or not based on the issue country of BOND, without changing `NLS_TERRITORY`

`SELECT TO_CHAR(ISSUE_DATE,'DY') DAY FROM BOND;`

In the above dates `18-AUG-2017` is a weekend in `ISRAEL` but not in `INDIA`

Comment: What do you consider as "weekend"? Always the 6th and 7th day of a week? For example in America the first day of week is Sunday, i.e. weekend are day 1 and 7. In Europe the first day of week is typically Monday, so weekend are day 6 and 7. In order to get the "first" day of week you must use `TRUNC(ISSUE_DATE,'D')`, however the result depends (always and only) on current `NLS_TERRITORY`. There is no way to bypass this. Maybe as a workaround write a function which determines the day of week in autonomous transaction.

Comment: if it is that critical for you, write a wrapper UDF (user defined function) that will set appropriate nls_territory at session level during the context of that function (and reset afterwords) and derive weekends. There is no universal definition of weekend, in Middle-east it could be Fri/Sat where-as it could be Sat/Sun everywhere else, so you must interpret it yourself and hence the UDF.

Answer (score -1):

Try to test the following:

```
select
TO_CHAR (issue_date, 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=HINDI) IN (6, 7)
from table
```

To see if it works for you. One thing you need to check is, depending on the country, if the week starts at a Monday or Sunday. You might have to change those in values accordingly.
Edit: doing this, you're only changing the value on the query. Isn't it what you wanted? And sorry for not getting the value right. Corrected.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to change NLS_DATE everytime, as I'm writing this in a PL/SQL block and fetching country based on bond input.

Comment: `'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=INDIA'` won't work, of course, because `INDIA` is [not a valid value for `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/applocaledata.htm#NLSPG581). The closest would be `HINDI`, but it won't affect the result of `TO_CHAR(..., 'D')`. On the other hand, `INDIA` would be valid for `NLS_TERRITORY`, but that parameter is not allowed in `TO_CHAR`. On the whole, this option was certainly worth exploring, but so far it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Aravind it's not "changing the NLS_DATE everytime" -- it's just specified as a parameter to the `to_char` function affecting which NLS parameters are used for just that `to_char` function call.

Comment: But this approach doesn't work, because, like @AndriyM mentions, NLS_TERRITORY is not a valid parameter to `to_char`.

Comment: Should be like this `WHERE TO_CHAR(issue_date, 'fmDY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=HINDI') in ('शनि','रवि')`